# php 7.0 - PHP max_execution_time doesn't change anything

Tags: php

I use a python script to **scrape** link from the firefox API. The script needs at least ~10-15 secs to finish the work.

I try to run it in PHP via

`shell_exec('cd keywords/ && python3 keywords.py ' . $file. ".txt")`

it perfectly work on Windows (xampp) but when I try to use it on Linux, after increasing the max_execution_time in the php.ini, adding `php_value max_execution_time 3000` and
`set_time_limit(3000); ini_set('max_execution_time', '3000');` at the top of my PHP file, PHP do not want to let my script run.

At the end of my python script, I remove some files, but when I run it via PHP, the file's are not removed and the script doesn't finish his work. When I run it via terminal (python3 keyword.py), it perfectly works.

Please help me

Comment: Did you confirm with `phpinfo()` that you are changing the right config?

Comment: Why do you think it's timing out? Have you confirmed it runs at all? Don't use relative paths, and ensure your values are properly escaped with `escapeshellarg()`

Comment: doesn't sound like its timing out, as your running file commands its more likely a permission issue. the user who runs it manually may have the permission to delete the files whereas the php user may not.

Comment: @Dharman Yes
@miken32 @tim The script is supposed to scrap keyword on firefox API via a list of word (the script : https://hastebin.com/iwatagetak.py), when I run manually, I scrap around 200 keywords, with PHP it show me only 3 keywords and the file are not deleted. That's why I think it's caused by `max_execution_time` (that is correctly set to 3000 (`echo 'Time Limit = ' . ini_get('max_execution_time');`))

Comment: I also tried to increase the apache2 max execution time, but it doesn't work..

Comment: FYI it's __scrape__ not scrap.